# twisted web server not serving files

Tags: python, twisted.web

here i have this little example snippet and it just wont serve index.html from www dir. what is wrong with the code?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import static, server, script
import os

DIRECTORY = os.getcwd()+"/www"
root = static.File(DIRECTORY)
root.indexNames = [ 'index.rpy', 'index.html' ]
root.processors = { '.rpy': script.ResourceScript }
site = server.Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(8090, site)
reactor.run()
```

all i get is 'No Such Resource' message. Is there any way to set up logging or something to figure this out?

Comment: Your index.rpy needs to include `resource = ...`.  Newer versions of twisted give a more informative error message.

Answer (score 2):

Logging can be set up by adding these lines

```
from twisted.python import log
import sys
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
```

Comment: thanks. tho logging doesnt reveal anything that could lead to solution of problem: [HTTPChannel,0,127.0.0.1] 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2011:17:21:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0"

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error, I had to add the following:

```
def getChild(self, name, request):
    # for some reason this is needed for the root Resource to render at all
    if name == b'':
        return self
    return super().getChild(name, request)
```